# How does the redirect_uri set itself to the correct value in Katana OAuth clients?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin, katana

If you look at the code snippets below, Katana sets the `redirect_uri` / callback path to some strange value for all providers.

```
public FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
  : base(Constants.DefaultAuthenticationType)
{
  CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-facebook");
  ...
}


public LinkedInAuthenticationOptions() : base("LinkedIn")
{
  this.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin");
  ...
}
```

How and where then does it reset this to the correct uri of the action that will handle the callback?

Answer (score 2):

The callback path is different from the `redirect_uri` you are thinking of.  For the purposes of this explanation,

- CallbackPath is the URI in your app that handles responses from the Identity Provider
- RedirectUri is the resource the user is trying to access
- `redirect_uri` is the parameter of the oAuth request

If you look in the `ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()` method of the `xxxAuthenticationHandler` class, you will see where `properties.RedirectUri` is set to the current URI, unless you have specified your own value in the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` notification.  In the redirect to the Identity Provider, `redirect_uri` is set to the CallbackPath, and the `properties` object is passed along in the state parameter.

When the Identity Provider redirects back to your app (specifically, the CallbackPath), the `Invoke` method is called, which in turn calls `InvokeReplyPathAsync()`, which then checks if the current URI is the CallbackPath before executing.  Then, the `RedirectUri` is retrieved from the properties object, the `ClaimsPrincipal` object is built, and the user is then redirected to their ultimate destination, the `RedirectUri`.